# Fatal error (13): No program entry point with XDS Modula-2?

Tags: modula-2

I'm using the current bundled binaries from https://github.com/excelsior-oss/xds (as of 12/6/2020) with just the most basic Hello World MOD file:

```
MODULE HelloWorld;

FROM STextIO IMPORT WriteLn, WriteString;

BEGIN

   WriteString("Hello, World!");
   WriteLn;

END HelloWorld.
```

`xc HelloWorld.mod` works fine for compiling it to object.  However, I'm not clear on the exact syntax for xlink on a standalone MOD file.  `xlink HelloWorld.obj` will at least get it to try with my object file, but as the error shows, it doesn't know the entrypoint.  I've tried setting the entry point with the /ENTRY switch, but no luck doing it by module name.  I've also tried setting the /SYS to console, but again, no luck there.

I feel there's some trivial linker option or program directive needed, but I'm just not finding it via Google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a binary, use: `xc =a =make HelloWorld.mod`

The above is found in https://github.com/excelsior-oss/xds/blob/master/Sources/Doc/Comp/src/usage.tex .
It is unfortunate that XDS did not put PDFs of their documentation on github.  I suggest building the documentation from their LaTeX files.

**Edit**: I since learnt that the Wayback Machine has archived the XDS documentation here: https://web.archive.org/web/20060705213825/http://www.excelsior-usa.com/xdsdoc.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed, but just was not able to find!